# NodeJs socket io file not found

Tags: node.js, socket.io, plesk

I want to use socket io on web server. When I work on localhost everything is working. I installed files on plesk panel. Node modules is installed successfully. When I call index.html I get an error is http://example.com:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js not found. Where is my mistake?

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="socket" ng-controller="homeController">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://example.com:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>id</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Category</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="i in results">
                    <td>{{$index}}</td>
                    <td>{{i.status}}</td>
                    <td>{{i.category}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
    var app = angular.module('socket', []);
    app.controller('homeController', function ($scope) {
        var socket = io.connect('http://example.com:3000');
        socket.on('connected', function (data) {
            socket.emit('ready for data', {});
        });

        socket.on('update', function (data) {           
            $scope.results = data;
            if (!$scope.$$phase) $scope.$apply();
        });  
    });
</script>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```
const Express = require('express');
const Request = require('request');
const http = require('http');
const db = require('./lib/database');
const app = Express();
const server = http.createServer(app);

var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.emit('connected', { connected: true });
    socket.on('ready for data', function (data) {
     db.on('notification', function(title) {
         const sql = "select * from public.test";
         db.query(sql, (err, result) => {
          if (err) res.status(err.code).json({code: err.code, message: err.message}).end();
          socket.emit('update', result.rows);
         })
     });
    });
});

server.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

**1- express.static**

If you want to serve static file like JavaScript, CSS, Image etc, you can use express.static built-in middleware function.

The function signature is:

```
express.static(root, [options])
```

The root argument specifies the root directory from which to serve static assets. For more information on the options argument, see express.static.

For example, use the following code to serve images, CSS files, and JavaScript files in a directory named public:

```
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

Now, you can load the files that are in the public directory:

```
http://localhost:3000/images/kitten.jpg
http://localhost:3000/css/style.css
http://localhost:3000/js/app.js
http://localhost:3000/images/bg.png
http://localhost:3000/hello.html
```

**2- CDN**
Alternatively you can use CDN for socket.io.js or other libraries like jquery, bootstrap etc.

You can get CDN from here [socket.io cdn](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/socket.io)